# How to save Microsoft (GitHub, etc.) webpage so it will render properly using Chrome or Firefox-based web browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, backup, html, css

A few months ago I noticed that webpages from Firefox, Chrome, and some other web browsers do not display properly, as if the CSS files which are saved are not what is used for rendering in the web  browser. The CSS files appear to be identical.

This also happens with the browser extension [SingleFile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/single-file/). Years ago, the FireFox extension [Mozilla Archive Format, with MHT and Faithful Save](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/seamonkey/addon/mozilla-archive-format/) **would** locally save pages that would render properly in a web browser. The CSS files saved by the web browsers are the same as the web versions of those files.

I also noticed Microsoft is using some clever inline code in their "learn" site which appears to change code at the DOM level but that's a different issue.

Is there a way to save a local copy of a web page so that it renders properly with current Chrome or Firefox-based browsers?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no universal way, since there're no standards defined for that.

While there are extensions like [View Rendered Source](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/view-rendered-source/ejgngohbdedoabanmclafpkoogegdpob), which I personally recommend as one that has high accuracy in terms of copying all currently displayed elements, none of them has a guarantee to work on all websites.

For instance, various parts of the website, such as images or videos, could get inaccessible due to access permissions. Which could be prevented by downloading all assets in theory. Some external tools like [ArchiveBox](https://archivebox.io/) attempt to do so, but then again some websites attempt to block them. And it's not the best idea ever in terms of security - some problems are listed [here](https://github.com/ArchiveBox/ArchiveBox/wiki/Security-Overview#security-overview).

A better way to approach this would be to ask about specific website(s) and elements that you want to copy, then you'd possibly get more accurate answers.

Comment: What you say is true but that's not quite what I tried to describe. Try to save any basic static page from GitHub and you'll see that loading the save version from a file doesn't render properly. The top of the page, when viewed on GitHub, has a black background. The visible borders around areas also don't look the same. My question is about basic rendering.

Comment: Great addon you recommended. Thanks for that.

Comment: Well, this stinks. GItHub pages now required javascript to render properly. The extension you linked inspired me to search for a way to save rendered pages. There is a Chrome extension called Save Rendered HTML which saves ONLY the html, no element files. Maybe the "solution" is to find CSS files from before Microsoft decided to prevent accurate page saving and drop them in the elements of new saved pages...

Comment: Did you try the standalone app? That's 99% your best bet, although like I wrote it won't be perfect either. Browser extensions have their limitations.